# Magento 2 - Customer name validation

Tags: checkout, validation, form-validation

On the checkout shipping section the first and last name input fields have validation on them which doesn't accept hyphens (**-**) or **'** characters

I had a look in lib/mage/validation.js but can't see where this validation criteria would be coming from

Does anyone know where this can be changed please? As if some has a double barreled name like Smith-San or O'leary it throws a validation error

Comment: Any extension related to customer then it's create issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great answer but I wanted to share screenshots with you.

My best advice is to check the markup on the fields.  Check for either validation classes or knockout bindings.  Might give you an idea on what is happening.

But as you can see from screenshot default behaviour is just to have first name, last name as required fields.  On that basis I was able to add address with criteria you posted. No further validation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ahh I see thanks for the reply! it looks like the site I'm on has some funky custom validation going on somewhere then